# Good practices of Websphere MQ production deployment

Tags: deployment, version-control, ibm-mq, production-environment

I'm about to prepare a deployment specification for the Websphere MQ production environment. As always I hate reinventing the wheel hence the question:
Is there an article, specififaction of best practices when it comes to deploying and maintaining the Webshpere MQ production environment?

Here are more specific doubts of mine:

- Configuration versioning (MQSC, dmpmqcfg, etc).
- Deploying new objects (MQSC or manual instructions?)
- Deployment automation (maybe basing on the diff of dmpmqcfg?).
- Deploying and versioning configuration alterations.

Currently I am simply creating MQ objects manually and versioning the output of dmpmqcfg. However, in a while there are going to be too many deployments to handle it like this.

Comment: what is your production environment? What exactly are you going to deploy(What MQ objects are you going to create)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an extremely broad question so I'll try to respond before a moderator deletes it.  :-)

The answer depends on many things such as whether MQ clusters are in use, the approaches to high availability and disaster recovery, the security requirements, whether the QMgrs are configured as dedicated or shared infrastructure, etc.  However, there are a few patterns that I follow in almost all cases, including non-Production.  This is because things like monitoring and security tend to get dropped at deployment time if not tested in Dev and don't work as expected in Prod.

- I use a script to create my QMgrs in Production to insure that basics like generating the X.509 certificate (or CSR) is always done according to standards, that any exits or exit parm files are present, that certain SupportPac executables (like `q`) are present in `/opt/mqm/bin`, [circular queues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1103_mismes/1103_mismes.html), etc.  It also checks for negative factors such as GSKit not being installed.
- I have a baseline script that is run against all QMgrs.  This script sets up the DLQ, any queues for monitoring agents, enables events as required, sets up system services, trigger monitors, listeners, etc.  The exception is B2B gateway QMgrs which are handled in a class all their own and have very specific configurations not used on the internal network.
  cluster.
- I have several classes of QMgr with specific configuration requirements.  These include cluster repositories (where primary and secondary are distinct sub-types), service-provider QMgrs, and service consumer QMgrs.  These all have secondary scripts run against them.
- I have scripts per-cluster to join or suspend a QMgr in cases where clustering is used (which for me is almost 100% since v7.1).

These set up a QMgr's infrastructure.  Then I maintain scripts for each application.  So for example, if there's a Payroll app, I'll have queues and possibly topics with names containing a `PAY` node such as `PAY.EMPLOYEE.UPDT.REQ.V032.PRD`.  Corresponding to that will be a single script for all `PAY.**` queues.  Used to be one for `setmqaut` commands too, but these are now in the same script as the objects.  I only ever have one version of the script and keep a history of changes in the script. This way when I need to recreate a QMgr, I just run all the scripts for it.  Similarly, if I need to deploy the `PAY` objects on another QMgr, I just copy the script to that server.

When defining objects for clusters, I always do a `DEFINE NOREPLACE` that contains all the run-time attributes such as whether the queue is enabled in the cluster.  The queue is always defined as disabled in the cluster and for triggering but because I use `NOREPLACE` re-running the script doesn't change whatever state it has in, say, a month.  Those things that are configuration and not run-time, such as the description, are handled in an `ALTER` immediately after the `DEFINE` and these *are* updated each time the script is run.  There's an article on this [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0811_mismes/0811_mismes.html).

Finally, the scripts I use are of the self-executing, self-documenting variety.  For example, many people put all the MQSC commands into a script then do something like:

```
runmqsc < payroll.mqsc > payroll.out
```

TONS of problems here.  The main one is that it relies on the operator to know a lot and execute the script right all the time.  For example, suppose (s)he forgets to capture the output?  Or overwrites a previous output?  Or doesn't get `STDERR` because (s)he needs to do the `2>&1` at the end and doesn't know redirection that well?

So my scripts are all written in `ksh` handle all the capturing of output, complete with time and date stamping and `STDERR`, can freely mix MQSC with OS commands, etc.  All you do is go to the scripts directory for that QMgr and `. ./*ksh` to build/rebuild a QMgr.

I do of course also take regular configuration dumps, but these are more for running queries and reports like "how many QMgrs have this channel defined and where are they?" kind of thing.

Also, when taking backups there is almost NEVER a good reason to back up a QMgr at a point in time.  However, if it is required be sure to stop the QMgr first.  Also, think long and hard about capturing certificates in a backup.  Many people are good about locking the certificate directory so only `mqm` can read it but often the backups are unprotected.  As long as you aren't trying to restore on top of Production, many shops let you restore the Production `/var/mqm/*` files to your own sandbox.  If the QMgr's KDB files are included, you just lost them.  An alternative is to put the certificates in `/etc` or some other directory that is protected but not backed up with the QMgr's directories.